# 'gltfjsx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: react-three-fiber, gltf

I have an archive.gltf. I want to transform it into JSX using gltf pipeline
This command is not working
npx gltfjsx archivegltf --transform

error:
'gltfjsx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

how can i solve it?

I tried to look for solution in google but wans table to find a suitable one.

Comment: Please search this site for **not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**. This question has been asked and answered literally dozens (if not hundreds) of times here before. Certainly one of the existing answers will help you solve the problem. We expect you to make a reasonable effort to solve the problem yourself before posting here, and part of that effort involves a thorough search. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages before you begin posting.